# NumPy min/max in-place assignment

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to perform min/max in-place assignment with NumPy multi-dimensional arrays without an extra copy?

Say, `a` and `b` are two 2D numpy arrays and I would like to have `a[i,j] = min(a[i,j], b[i,j])` for all `i` and `j`.

One way to do this is:

```
a = numpy.minimum(a, b)
```

But according to the documentation, `numpy.minimum` creates and returns a new array:

> numpy.minimum(x1, x2[, out])
>   Element-wise minimum of array elements.
>   Compare two arrays and returns **a new array** containing the element-wise minima.

So in the code above, it will create a new temporary array (min of `a` and `b`), then assign it to `a` and dispose it, right?

Is there any way to do something like `a.min_with(b)` so that the min-result is assigned back to `a` in-place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`numpy.minimum()` takes an optional third argument, which is the output array. You can specify `a` there to have it modified in place:

```
In [9]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 1]])

In [10]: b = np.array([[3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]])

In [11]: np.minimum(a, b, a)
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 1]])

In [12]: a
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: Indeed it does take the third parameter. Thanks! :)

Comment: It would improve answer slightly to print `id(a)` before and after.

Comment: @jwpat7: I didn't bother since there's no way simply calling a function can rebind `a` to point to a different object.