# numpy/pylab min, max

Tags: python, numpy

I have two array of numbers t,x:

```
import numpy
t = numpy.arange(0,10,0.001)
x = numpy.sin(t)
```

I want to produce other arrays of the same size which are the element-by-element maximum or minimum:

```
y1 = ?max(x,2)
y2 = ?min(x,t)
```

where `?max` and `?min` stand for unknown functions. The `numpy.max()` and `numpy.min()` seem to find the max and min of an entire array, which is not what I want.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NumPy min/max in-place assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428183/numpy-min-max-in-place-assignment)

Comment: Argh -- I did search stackoverflow first before asking. Honestly!

Comment: I think the two questions are rather different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`numpy.minimum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and [`numpy.maximum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html#numpy.maximum) (not to be confused with `numpy.min()` and `numpy.max()`).

Comment: Thanks, just found those in the duplicate question I cited. What a confusing choice of function names. :-(